# Why does my socket.io code emit the message to everyone connected, when I specifically wrote socket.in(room)...?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, p2p

I am trying to set up a webrtc app. For now, it connects two people when they click connect. But if I have multiple connections open, and then when one of the people from the very first connection clicks disconnect, it literally disconnects EVERYONE who has a connection. I tried this with 3 connections, and disconnected the 2nd connection, and that only makes the 3rd connection disconnect, while the first is still connected. 
So basically, it's a downward spiral. If a connection disconnects, then all connections created AFTER that one connection also get to disconnect. But all connections before that connection are still active.

I think it has something to do with the socket.io code, because in the console.log I am receiving the message from socket.io as someone in a totally different connection disconnects. Server code:

```
        socket.on("sessiondesc", function(sessiondesc)
        {
          if (sessiondesc == true || sessiondesc.type === 'answer')
          {
              //the random room is generated before the socket.on sessiondesc thing. 
              socket.join(room)
          }
        socket.in(room).emit("sessiondesc", sessiondesc);
        });

        socket.on("quit", function(quit)
        {
            socket.leave(room)
        });
```

This is client code:

```
    socket.on("sessiondesc", function(sessiondesc)
    {
     //stuff I do here with webrtc... like create offer, answer, and such. 
     else if (sessiondesc == false)
     {
      pc.close();
      pc = null;
      console.log("GOT THE FALSE SESSION DESC! GOT IT");
      quit = true;

      socket.emit("quit", quit);
      }


        document.getElementById("disconnect").addEventListener("click",   function(e)
         {
          console.log("The person clicked disconnect!");
          quit = true;
          sessiondesc = false;
          socket.emit("sessiondesc", sessiondesc);
          socket.emit("quit", quit);
          pc.close();
          pc = null;

    });
```

So basically on all the other connections that disconnect, I can see the console.log("GOT THE SESSION DESC") thing... And I'm thinking like, why are these other rooms getting this sessiondesc? They shouldn't be, I'm only emitting it to a specific room!

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but, when you click, you send `sessiondesc = false` . It launch this line: `socket.in(room).emit("sessiondesc", sessiondesc = false);` And this launch a quit event on all clients because of `if (sessiondesc == false)`. In your test I think the second socket was removed from the room before removing the first one.

Comment: But if I'm only emitting the sessiondesc = false in one single room, why is it going to all the other clients? It should only be going to the clients in the room.

Comment: Is there a default room ?

Comment: No, the rooms are generated randomly. They should all be unique. I kind of figured it out a little bit, by just keeping track of the rooms, but for some reason right now it's doing an infinite socket callback loop. See my other question about that, it has the recent code.

Comment: FYI: All sockets are in a room determined by their `id` by default. I read this in the doc here: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room